# getClickwrapAgreements not returning documents

Tags: docusignapi

The getClickwrapAgreements call is not returning a list of documents associated with that agreement. According to the [API documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/click-api/reference/Accounts/ClickWraps/getClickwrapAgreements/), this call should return a `documents` array of objects containing e.g. `documentBase64`, `documentName`, `fileExtension`, but that array is always empty.

Example request:

```
https://demo.docusign.net/clickapi/v1/accounts/<accountid>/clickwraps/<clickwrapId>/users?client_user_id=<userId>
```

Example response:

```
{
    "userAgreements": [
        {
            "accountId": "<accountId>",
            "clickwrapId": "<clickwrapId>",
            "clientUserId": "<userId>",
            "agreementId": "<agreementId>",
            "documents": [],
            "createdOn": "2020-09-25T11:30:26.8230097Z",
            "agreedOn": "2020-09-25T11:30:34.5580771Z",
            "status": "agreed",
            "versionId": "e90d4cb6-868b-48a3-9b1c-5a7f2083102d",
            "versionNumber": 8,
            "settings": {
                "hasDeclineButton": false,
                "actionButtonAlignment": "left",
                "mustRead": false,
                "mustView": false,
                "requireAccept": false,
                "downloadable": true,
                "sendToEmail": false,
                "brandId": "68cbc4b1-a78f-4e72-889e-0554141da176",
                "format": "inline",
                "documentDisplay": "document"
            }
        }
    ],
    "beginCreatedOn": "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "page": 0,
    "pageSize": 40,
    "minimumPagesRemaining": 0
}
```

When I navigate to the Manage Clickwraps page in the Docusign website, I'm able to download the certificate associated with the agreement. If I enabled the recipient to download the agreement, they are also able to download it after agreeing.

For context, I need to store a copy of every user's agreement certificate in the back end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this. This appears to be a bug with Clickwraps -- which I will report internally to have addressed. In the meantime, I was able to reproduce this issue, and can confirm that the document nodes are indeed coming back blank if hitting the user agreement in any form.

However, I was able to find this: In the call you're already making, you can see in the response there's parameter for agreementId. I did some tinkering and found that if I hit this URI:
"https://demo.docusign.net/clickapi/v1/accounts/{ACCOUNTID}/clickwraps/{clickwrapID}/agreements/{agreementId}/download?include_coc=true", I was able to download the PDF associated with that agreement. The url parameter for include coc determines if the additional certificate of completion is added onto the PDF.